# How can i disable keyboard capturing in hyperv

Tags: keyboard, hyper-v

I have a script written in python that emulates keystrokes and mouse clicks which is currently running on vm. I want to have the script running on vm when i can do some other stuff on other desktop, however, keyboard is not working when i'm on other desktop. How can i disable keyboard capturing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

In Hyper-V Manager you can navigate to 'Hyper-V Manager -> $YOUR_DESKTOP -> Hyper-V Settings... -> User -> Keyboard -> Use on the physical computer'.

This setting modifies Host->Guest interactions. I'm not sure if these settings will allow you flexibility with Guest->Host keyboard inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Open Hyper-V Manager.

Go to Hyper-V Settings.

Then, left side, under Users, set Keyboard to be used on the Physical Computer.  This will be best. Consider also set to use on VM only when VM is running Full Screen. This might help. I think the Physical Computer is your best option.